# Combinatorial Argument (in Summation Notation)

Tags: combinatorics, summation, combinations, binomial-coefficients

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{n} {n\choose k} (-2)^{k + 1} $$

I am suffering to answer this question..

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: "I am suffering to answer this question" - but what is the question?

Comment: Have you learned the binomial theorem?

Comment: Further hint... $\binom{n}{k}(-2)^{k+1} = \binom{n}{k}(-2)^{k+1}\cdot 1 = \binom{n}{k}(-2)^{k+1}\cdot 1\cdot 1$... you can always multiply something by $1$ as many times as you like without changing the value.

Comment: A question that can be answered using a combinatorial argument would include an **equation** that could be "explained" using different ways of counting. A natural prerequisite for a number to be a result of counting things is to be non-negative.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your question is whether there is a simple reduction the the expression you wrote. If so, then the answer is simple:

$$
\sum^n_{k=0}\binom{n}{k}(-2)^{k+1}=-2\sum^n_{k=0}\binom{n}{k}(1)^{n-k}(-2)^k=-2(1-2)^n=-2(-1)^n=2(-1)^{n+1}$$